# How to check an exectuable's path is correct in PHP?

Tags: php, security, shell

I'm writing a setup/installer script for my application, basically just a nice front end to the configuration file. One of the configuration variables is the executable path for mysql. After the user has typed it in (for example: `/path/to/mysql-5.0/bin/mysql` or just `mysql` if it is in their system PATH), I want to verify that it is correct. My initial reaction would be to try running it with `"--version"` to see what comes back. However, I quickly realised this would lead to me writing this line of code:

```
shell_exec($somethingAUserHasEntered . " --version");
```

...which is obviously a Very Bad Thing. Now, this is a setup script which is designed for trusted users only, and ones which probably already have relatively high level access to the system, but still I don't think the above solution is something I want to write.

Is there a better way to verify the executable path? Perhaps one which doesn't expose a massive security hole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running arbitrary user commands is like running queries based on user input... Escaping is the key.

First, validate if it is an executable using [`is_executable()`](http://php.net/is_executable).

PHP exposes two functions for this: [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) and [`escapeshellcmd()`](http://php.net/escapeshellcmd).

[`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) adds single quotes around a string and quotes/escapes any existing single quotes allowing you to pass a string directly to a shell function and having it be treated as a single safe argument.

[`escapeshellcmd()`](http://php.net/escapeshellcmd) escapes any characters in a string that might be used to trick a shell command into executing arbitrary commands.

This should limit the amount of risk.

```
if(is_executable($somethingAUserHasEntered)) {
  shell_exec(escapeshellarg($somethingAUserHasEntered) . " --version");
}
```

After all, doing `rm --version` isn't very harmful, and `"rm -rf / &&" --version` will get you anywhere very fast.

---

**EDIT:** Since you mentioned `PATH`... Here is a quick function to validate if the file is an executable according to `PATH` rules:

```
function is_exec($file) {
  if(is_executable($file)) return true;
  if(realpath($file) == $file) return false; // Absolute Path

  $paths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $_ENV['PATH']);

  foreach($paths as $path) {
    // Make sure it has a trailing slash
    $path = rtrim($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    if(is_executable($path . $file)) return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 Personally I woudl not even prompt the user, but would just step along the path looking for the .exe  Yes, I suppose that they _could_ rename mysql, but how realistic is that? In the worst case you could output "Sorry, I can't find mysql(.exe) on the path <path value>. Is it installed? Perhaps you renamed it?"

Answer (score 1):

You could try a simple `file_exists` call to determine if **something** exists at that location, along with an `is_executable` to confirm that it's something you can run.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at `is_dir()` or `is_link()` or `is_file()` or `is_readable()`

Hope these help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the guy with 45k reputation points is aware of basic PHP file functions...

Comment: @Matchu lol - i think rep is more of a measure of your spare time than anything else. :-p. @Robert thanks, I have seen these, but they don't help when the file is in the system PATH.

Answer (score 0):

`system('which '.escapeshellarg($input))` will give you the absolute path to the executable, regardless if it's just the name or an absolute path.